# Best practices in repeating request if request failed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I'm curious about best practices in repeating a failed request using the `requests` library in Python3. I have a simple API wrapper that makes a get request to a constructed URL. If an exception is raised by `requests`, I'd like to retry the request before raising an exception.

I'm unsure if there's some standard practice that I'm unaware of. What I have will repeat the request 10x, doubling the wait time between requests in each iteration.

```py
import time
import requests
from requests.exceptions import RequestException


def get_request(*args, max_retry=10, **kwargs):
    """ Gets requests.models.Response object using requests.get.
    Retry request if request fails, with number of iteration specified
    by max_retry. """

    def recurse_get_request(*args, retries=0, wait=0.005, **kwargs):
        try:
            return requests.get(*args, **kwargs)
        except RequestException as exc:
            if retries > max_retry:
                raise RequestException from exc

            print("Request failed: (%s). Retrying after %s seconds ..." % (exc, "%.2f" % wait))
            time.sleep(wait)
            # double the wait time after every iteration
            wait *= 2
            retries += 1
            return recurse_get_request(*args, retries=retries, wait=wait, **kwargs)

    return recurse_get_request(*args, **kwargs)


get_request('https://sfbay.craigs.org')  # bad url
```

Comment: Doubling the time between requests (or an [exponential increase in delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) in general) is the best practice as far as I'm aware (you can also add jitter). You should check out the [tenacity](https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for retrying requests with a decorator.

Comment: IMHO it's ok and it's kinda standard procedure. But why make it recursive instead of a for-loop? It's quite hard to understand what's going on. I would put a maximum on the wait time as well. Otherwise at max_retry=20, it will take 1.5 hours already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is called [truncated exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff), and it's quite good already. It's called "truncated" because it eventually stops retrying and gives up entirely.

The linked description on Wikipedia also implements randomization, which I would call truncated *randomized* exponential backoff. Randomization is not necessary if there's only a single client, but if there are multiple clients competing for the same resource using the same backoff schedule, you could run into the [thundering herd problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem). Randomization helps to avoid this.

The Python package [Tenacity](https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) helps you implement all this easily with a nice unobtrusive decorator. Here's an example of how I'm using it:

```py
import tenacity

# Retry 10 times, starting with 1 second and doubling the delay every time.
_RETRY_ARGS = {
    'wait': tenacity.wait.wait_random_exponential(multiplier=1.0, exp_base=2),
    'stop': tenacity.stop.stop_after_attempt(10)
}

@tenacity.retry(**_RETRY_ARGS)
def something_that_might_fail():
    ...

@tenacity.retry(**_RETRY_ARGS)
def something_else_that_might_fail():
    ...
```